# How to do class type inside class type?

Tags: class

do you know how to do a class-type inside another class-type?
Let's say I have a LinkedList class, and I want to do a Node class inside.

```
class LinkedList
{

class Node
{
 int val;
 Node *next;
 Node *prev;

};

};
```

And now I want to write methods in a .cpp file for the Node class. Can I write them in the .cpp file of the LinkedList, or do I have to make a new .cpp file for the node?
**And how do I do that?**

Comment: P.S how do I create a pointer in the LinkedList to the Node object it is holding?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I was doing c++, but if I remember correctly you would put them in the same .cpp file. The trick is to define them including the containing class name:

```
Node* LinkedList::Node::getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this : [Nested Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23h0937%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

This is an example which shows how to declare nested class.

Comment: Thanks.P.S how do I create a pointer in the LinkedList to the Node object it is holding?